# Restemplate getforobject to java class

Tags: java, spring

I want to parse the following json to a java class:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 5,
    "lat": 51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 211,
      "main": "Thunderstorm",
      "description": "onweersbui",
      "icon": "11d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 20.84,
    "pressure": 995,
    "humidity": 77,
    "temp_min": 18,
    "temp_max": 23
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.6,
    "deg": 90
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 75
  },
  "dt": 1494516300,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 4842,
    "message": 0.0047,
    "country": "BE",
    "sunrise": 1494474907,
    "sunset": 1494530314
  },
  "id": 7668893,
  "name": "Scherpenheuvel-Zichem",
  "cod": 200
}
```

the code to for the parsing is:

```
Weatherinformation response = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, Weatherinformation.class);
```

Weatherinformation class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Weatherinformation {

private Main main;
private List weather;
private String name;

public List getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

public void setWeather(List weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Main getMain() {
    return this.main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Weather {

    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Main {

    private double temp;
    private double temp_min;
    private double temp_max;

    public double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public double getTemp_min() {
        return temp_min;
    }

    public void setTemp_min(double temp_min) {
        this.temp_min = temp_min;
    }

    public double getTemp_max() {
        return temp_max;
    }

    public void setTemp_max(double temp_max) {
        this.temp_max = temp_max;
    }
}

}
```

Everything is working so far except getting the description of the weather.

Comment: json data you provide is not in correct format

Comment: The JSON format is riddled of errors and doesn't match with the Java class.

Comment: oops normally not, that just happend with placing this post. just corrected it @AshrafulIslam

Comment: why aren't you using generics. Did you try with `List<Weather>` instead of just List in Weatherinformation class

Comment: tried that but dind't work @pvpkiran

Comment: Is this Weather class inner class of WeatherInformation?

Comment: yes but I don't see any problem with that@pvpkiran

Comment: put it in a different class and try

Comment: Thanks! it works, with using list<Weather> and seperated classes. @pvpkiran

Comment: No Worries. Jackson has some issues with inner class when it  tries to deserialize. Give it a tick if its helful :) Or I can add it as answer So that you can accept and helpful for others

Comment: just add it to the anwers an will give it a solution mark @pvpkiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Weather` inner class from inside `WeatherInformation`  and make it a separate class or make the inner class static.

Answer (score -1):

I think "List weather" should be "Weather[]" in WeatherInformation class.

Comment: that gives me this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of view.controller.Weatherinformation$Weather: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)